# How to send information simultaneously to two different websites in separate tabs of Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm facing a challenge in my current project and wondering if it's possible to send information to two different websites in separate tabs of Google Chrome simultaneously. My requirement is to automatically send the entered text field value on "site 1" to "site 2" without manually duplicating the action.

I have researched possible solutions but haven't found a direct approach for this specific problem. One idea was to duplicate the mouse cursor or use some sort of bot to perform this task, but I'm uncertain if these solutions are the best or if there are more suitable alternatives.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to solve this situation. Is there a specific library or extension for Google Chrome that allows simultaneous sending of information to multiple websites in separate tabs? Or perhaps there is a different approach I can take?

Thank you in advance for any guidance or help provided.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is not a perfect solution, but it's already done, is to bookmark javascript. When you click a bookmark that has javascript it will execute the script in the current page.

In this example i will fill gmail account forms in 2 different tabs.

**1 -** Have your bookmarks always visible by hitting `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `B`

**2 -** Create a new bookmark with this code (The script will prompt for an input that will be split by `|` and put index 0 into Fist Name and index 1 into Last Name)

```
javascript:values = prompt("Data:");

document.querySelector("#firstName").value = values.split("|")[0];
document.querySelector("#firstName").dispatchEvent(
    new window.Event('input', { bubbles: true })
);

document.querySelector("#lastName").value = values.split("|")[1];
document.querySelector("#lastName").dispatchEvent(
    new window.Event('input', { bubbles: true })
);
```

**Bookmark will look like this:**

[image]

**And in the bookmark bar like this**

[image]

**3 -** Open two tabs with this link

https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/createaccount?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=SignUp

**4 -** Have this text in you clipboard: `First Name|Last Name`

**5 -** Go to a tab, click the bookmark, paste the value and press enter, go to the other tab and repeat

[image]
[image]

**Now if you need this to be even more automatic then I am afraid the only option will be for you to develop you own Chrome Extension.**